# Is there a relationship between the initial length of a pendulum that is released in air, and the amplitudes half-life (defined in post)?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, drag, oscillators

If I were to release an underdamped pendulum right now in earth's regular atmosphere, factoring in air resistance, is there a way to plot the motion of the pendulum using a regular function? Also, does the initial pendulum length impact the time taken for the continuous amplitude to reach half of the initial amplitude?

Apologies if this is a basic question,